# Deserialize Vec<u8> into readable (raw) json

Tags: json, rust, serde

I'm working with a `http::request::Request` that I'm getting after calling this function: https://docs.rs/kube/0.76.0/kube/core/struct.Request.html#method.patch_subresource.

The call looks like that:

```rust
        let mut pp = PatchParams::default();
        pp.field_manager = Some(String::from("application/apply-patch"));
        let req = self
            .mfs
            .patch_subresource("status", &self.name, &pp, &Patch::Apply(data))
            .map_err(ErrorKind::KubeApi)?;
```

I'm actually debugging this part, so I don't know exactly what should be in the body of this request. However, I know that `req.body()` is a `&Vec<u8>`, and I know that this data can be deserialized to json.

I *just* want to deserialize this `Vec<u8>` to readable json. Nothing else. But this proved surprisingly difficult.

I tried many approaches like that without much success (when I print `body` I see an array of int).

```rust
let data: &Vec<u8> = req.body();
let body: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_slice(data).unwrap();
```

The output is something like that:

```
[123,34,115,116,97,116,117,115,34,58...
```

I know this isn't *really* an array of int, it's just the debug version of `Vec<u8>`. So my attempt at decoding the body to json doesn't really work here.

Note that:

```
let body = String::from_utf8(req.body().clone()).unwrap();
```

Outputs something like that:

```
"{\"status\":{\"conditions\":{\"generated\":{\...
```

-> This is the debug version of a string, not the debug version of some json

Is totally readable, but I'm really trying to get some raw json here. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "raw json" a `String`? A `serde_json::Value`

Comment: If you see an array of ints when you print `body`, then probably your JSON contains an array of ints...

Comment: > What do you mean by "raw json"

I want to get some json (something like the equivalent of a dict in Python) that I can then display, not the string version of the data. I edited my post to make it clearer.

Comment: The JSON crate can do that

Comment: That's what `serde_json::Value` is can you please provide the input and expected output to make this a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How exactly are you printing `body`, the `serde_json::Value`? Take a look at this example and see what you're doing wrong: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=74f103205b1ac742d0b50233871b8eca

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm curious, why is the `use serde_json;` at the top?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Just a braino, that line can (and should) be omitted.

Comment: When you say that `body` is "the debug version of a string", I assume you're printing it with `{:?}`. Does printing it with `{}` give you what you want?

Comment: :facepalm: I had it since the beginning...Thanks @Jmb, I can just print it with `{}`.